# Filter counts per day and counts per month

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, group-by

I'm trying to filter a table with Ids and dates. My question is; how many unique Ids show up during a month? I took a small snippet from the DB, which can be viewed at the bottom of this post.

## Conditions

- **only** count a unique Id per day. Meaning even if an Id shows up 2 times a day, we only count the Id as one time for that day
- **only** count Ids that are shown **at least** 2 times per month. Meaning we exclude

It feels like there is a short way to execute this, which I want to learn. So far I've split the dates into shorter varchars of example "30-01-2018", where I can filter away multiplicates from each date. Then I've done a counting on distinct tagids. This seems to work, but involves like 4-5 separate temporary tables. Is there a better way to sort this in one single shot?

## Database

Dates **Datetime**
Id **varchar**

```
+-------------------------+-----+
|          Dates          | Id  |
+-------------------------+-----+
| 2018-01-30 08:37:51.450 | 158 |
| 2018-01-31 08:43:04.317 | 158 |
| 2018-01-31 08:32:43.977 | 143 |
| 2018-01-31 12:51:12.720 | 143 |
| 2018-01-30 08:35:51.777 |  89 |
| 2018-01-30 12:47:52.817 | 189 |
| 2018-01-31 08:46:58.913 |  89 |
| 2018-01-31 08:29:23.077 | 109 |
| 2018-01-30 07:10:00.267 |  31 |
| 2018-01-31 06:01:54.813 |  31 |
| 2018-01-31 12:36:04.583 |  31 |
| 2018-01-30 08:07:27.320 | 187 |
| 2018-01-30 08:08:11.917 | 226 |
| 2018-01-30 12:20:00.240 | 226 |
| 2018-01-31 08:17:59.257 | 226 |
| 2018-01-30 09:20:23.577 | 167 |
| 2018-01-31 12:40:30.977 | 167 |
| 2018-01-31 14:02:18.563 | 167 |
+-------------------------+-----+
```

Thanks!

Comment: "how many unique Ids show up during a month" vs "only count a unique Id per day" and "only count Ids that are shown at least 2 times per month"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group your data by year and month. Then `COUNT(*)` gives you number of items per month e.g. 31 appears 3 times in 2018-01, 143 appears two times in 2018-01, 167 appears three times in 2018-01 and so on.

But you want to consolidate items on same day together thus `COUNT(DISTINCT DAY(Dates))` gives you the desired number e.g. 143 appears once in 2018-01 (both occurrences on 31st).

```
SELECT Id, YEAR(Dates) YY, MONTH(Dates) MM, COUNT(DISTINCT DAY(Dates)) AS C
FROM testdata
GROUP BY Id, YEAR(Dates), MONTH(Dates)
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DAY(Dates)) >= 2
```

Output:

```
| Id  | YY   | MM | C |
|-----|------|----|---|
| 31  | 2018 | 1  | 2 |
| 89  | 2018 | 1  | 2 |
| 158 | 2018 | 1  | 2 |
| 167 | 2018 | 1  | 2 |
| 226 | 2018 | 1  | 2 |
```

Comment: Wow, LOVE your solution! Learned so much from this! Thank you so much man :)